# Getting too many result on python browser

Tags: python, xpath, printing, xvfb, dryscrape

Friends i want to extract live scores on espncricinfo i try with dryscrape :-

```
Import dryscrape as d
d.start_xvfb()
br = d.Session()
br.visit('http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/index.html?view=live')
for x in br.xpath('//*[@class = "innings-info-1"]'):
 x
#print 4 results 
for y in br.xpath('//*[@class = "innings-info-2"]'):
 y
#print 4 results of 2nd innings
#but when i try combian then print tooo many results
for x in br.xpath('//*[@class = "innings-info-1"]'):
 for y in br.xpath('//*[@class = "innings-info-2"]'):
  x,'\n',y
#need 4+4=8 results but python prints 16 results
```

Please help me

Comment: i try with mechanize browse but failed to extract

Comment: Then i try zip(x,y) and for i in enumerate(x); print x, '\n', y[i] but failed

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting as an output. Why can't you just have separate `for` loops like you had before, instead of nesting them? Or you could do `for x, y in zip(br.xpath('//*[@class = "innings-info-1"]'), br.xpath('//*[@class = "innings-info-2"]')):` but that won't give you 8 results, you'll still only get 4 lines of printout.

Comment: Actually, I wasn't correct there, since you have `\n` in the `print` but then you end up with a strange misalignment in the output.

Comment: Thanks roganjosh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have double loop. First have 4 elements, second 4 element. So you iterate 4 times by second loop and get 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 = 16. Your code execute the way it should.

if you want to get list of result you can for example do it like this:

```
x = [x for x in br.xpath('//*[@class = "innings-info-1"]')]
y = [y for y in br.xpath('//*[@class = "innings-info-2"]')]
print(list(zip(x,y))
```